# Google Authentication doesn't work anymore after moving to a different OS

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I've recently switched to Ubuntu. I've put my Android project on Google Drive and then downloaded onto my new system. The project seemed to save fine, and it opens and runs OK.

However, it seems that my Google authentication doesnt work anymore without even changing the code. Any ideas what might be missing? I can post the code if it's necessary.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Update your SHA-1 in  Google authentication.

Comment: You have a different debug signing key on each of your machines. Do what Janak said OR copy the debug key from the original machine to your new machine.

Comment: A bunch of firebase errors, but those happened back when it worked aswell. @Janak This was it. Mind if I post a tutorial on how as a separate answer?

Comment: @Nephilim About a bunch of firebase errors?

Comment: @Janak I was replaying to Nadiger. :). Doesnt let me @ more than one person per comment. It's just one error and it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the debug key, the android.keystore file it's in :

$HOME/.android/debug.keystore on windows, dont know where on ubuntu, search it.
You can copy paste the new key if you have a backup or update your debug key in Google API : https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth

Comment: keytool -exportcert -list -v \ -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore